# Cython, OS X and link errors

Tags: python, gcc, cython

I've followed a simple tutorial on Cython with the following steps:

1. Make a simple python file, testme.py:

   print( "Hello there!!" )
2. Create a c file from that using cython:

   cython -a testme.py
3. Compile the resulting testme.c file with gcc:

   gcc -Os -I /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -o testme testme.c -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl

The result is quite a few lines like these:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyCode_New", referenced from:
      _inittestme in testme-4ef125.o
  "_PyDict_New", referenced from:
      _inittestme in testme-4ef125.o
  "_PyDict_SetItem", referenced from:
      _inittestme in testme-4ef125.o
  "_PyErr_Clear", referenced from:
      _inittestme in testme-4ef125.o
      _main in testme-4ef125.o
  "_PyErr_Occurred", referenced from:
      _inittestme in testme-4ef125.o
      _main in testme-4ef125.o
  "_PyErr_Print", referenced from:
      _main in testme-4ef125.o
  "_PyErr_SetString", referenced from:
      _inittestme in testme-4ef125.o
  "_PyErr_WarnEx", referenced from:
      _inittestme in testme-4ef125.o
  "_PyExc_ImportError", referenced from:
      _inittestme in testme-4ef125.o
  "_PyExc_RuntimeError", referenced from:
      _inittestme in testme-4ef125.o
```

Clearly, there's a missing link library.  I have the following

```
/usr/lib/libpython2.6.dylib -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python
```

but adding that to the gcc command gives me a XXX not found error:

```
gcc -Os -I /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -o hello testme.c -l/usr/lib/libpython2.6.dylib -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
ld: library not found for -l/usr/lib/libpython2.6.dylib
```

The path is correct.  The library is there.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link the correct libpython. E.g. `-lpython2.7`.

FWIW the `cython` command is a bit low-level (it *only* handles compilation of individual Cython modules to C), where as the `cythonize` command is a bit higher level, can work on entire packages, and also includes a `--build` option that handles compiling the C code.  This is generally easier than trying to build the correct `gcc` command yourself.

Comment: Thanks!  Using the right lib did the trick.  

One thing, I don't see a --build option for cython.  Were you referring to something else?

Comment: Glad it worked.  The `--build` option is part of `cythonize` actually.  I'll update my answer.